# running angular app before e-2-e tests

Tags: angular, protractor

I have written a few protractor tests against an angular 2 app. Both of them reside in the same repository (app and the tests). I need to run the app (npm start) on localhost before I can run those tests. whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of build tools that can accomplish this (eg. [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/), [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), etc...). Personally, I like to use [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), as they are simple, and already part of your project. For example, in your `package.json`, you could add something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "protractor conf.js"
  },
```

And then if you run your tests via `npm test`, `npm install` should get run before your tests run.

Comment: if you launch `npm test` it won't work as your localhost app is not started, is there a way to start the app then run protractor then stop the app ?

Comment: You can have Protractor start/stop Selenium automagically by specifying the jar [in your config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts).

Comment: Oh... you said _app_... well, sure, you could add a npm script to start your app too. Read the [npm script docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), they're pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Brine his answer, this is what I did for an Angular 2 project I'm working on. I need to start a server before I can run my tests.

I've created a `.js` file that will

- start the Angular app before running protractor on port 5555
- run the protractor tests, if you need to pass arguments you can, but it's not added in this script
- I'm using NPM scripts to run protractor, but you can add whatever you want in the `const child = child_process.exec('npm run e2e.local');` part

```js
// The server.js file
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const child_process = require('child_process');

const e2e = path.resolve(process.cwd(), './e2e-tests/config/');
const port = 5555;
const appFolder = path.resolve(process.cwd(), './dist/your-app-folder/');

/**
  * Start a server
  */
class Protractor {
  server(port, dir) {
    app.set('port', port);
    // Pass the folder the app should be run from
    app.use(express.static(dir));

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let server = app.listen(port, () => {
        resolve(server);
      });
    });
  }
}

/**
 * Start a server and run protractor.
 */
(() => {
  process.env.LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8';
  // I'm having some npm scripts that run the protractor config
  const child = child_process.exec('npm run e2e.local');
  new Protractor()
    // Start the server on port 5555
    .server(port, appFolder)
    .then((server) => {
      // Start protractor
      child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
      child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
      // Stop the server if Protractor crashes or we're done testing
      child.on('exit', () => {
        server.close();
      });
    });
})();
```

I hope this helps you.